# Why does function call change value of string in main function?

Tags: arrays, c, pass-by-reference, implicit-conversion, function-declaration

In the code, I wanted to reverse the string.

However, the function call changed the value of string `A` in the `main` function as well (The function is correct but I don't know why the function is changing the actual value of the string in the main function)

How could I reverse the string in `revstr` without modifying `A` from `main`?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void revstr(char A[], int l);

int main(){
    char A[20];
    
    scanf("%s", A);
    int l=strlen(A);
    revstr(A,l);
    printf("%s", A);
    return 0;
}
void revstr(char A[], int l){
    int x=0,y,temp;
    y=l-1;
    while(x<y){
        temp=A[x];
        A[x]=A[y];
        A[y]=temp;
        x++;
        y--;
        
    }
    printf("%s", A);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the array to the function call, (i.e., the pointer to the first element of the array), and from the called function, you're actually changing the contents of the memory locations.

The changes to these memory locations are not of a copy of the original array, rather taking place in the actual array itself. So, the changes made from the called function are *reflecting* in the caller function also. The actual array itself is getting modified, so when you try to print the array in the `main()` function, it already has it's contents modified, and that modified content is getting printed.

You need to keep a copy of the original array in the caller, if you want to refer the unmodified version later.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that what You are calling a string, really is an array of characters. As a consequence in the function You are not actually passing a string, but the location in memory (a pointer) of the first element of the char array.

So whats being manipulated in the function is whatever is stored at that specific location.

One way to work around this would be to pass an additional, empty array to the function in which the reversed string is stored.

Answer (score 0):

When a function is called the arguments are evaluated and each parameter is assigned the value of the corresponding argument.

For example you can imagine the definition if the function `revstr` and its call in main the following way (for clarity I renamed function parameters like `F_A` and `F_l`)

```
int main(){
char A[20];

scanf("%s", A);
int l=strlen(A);
revstr(A,l);
//...


void revstr( /*char F_A[], int F_l */ )
{
    char F_A[] = A;
    int F_l = l;
    //...
```

That is the function parameters are initialized by the values of the argument expressions.

But here is a problem. In this declaration

```
    char F_A[] = A;
```

we are trying to initialize an array with an array designator something like

```
char A[] = "Hello";
char F_A[] = A;
```

Such an initialization is incorrect. You may initialize a character array either with a string literal or with a braced list of initializers.

So how is this problem resolved in C?

For starters the compiler adjusts function parameters that have array types to pointers to array element types. Thus this function declaration

```
void revstr(char A[], int l);
```

is adjusted by the compiler to the declaration

```
void revstr(char *A, int l);
```

and the both declarations declare the same one function. You may include the both declarations of the function in your program though the compiler can issue a message that there are redundant function declarations.

On the other hand, when an array is used as an argument expression it is also implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

So in fact you have

```
void revstr( char *A, int l );

int main(){
char A[20];

scanf("%s", A);
int l=strlen(A);
revstr( &A[0], l );
//...
```

So within the function you are dealing with a pointer that points to the memory extent where the elements of the array `A` declared in main are situated. Using this pointer you are changing these elements that is the original array declared in main.

In fact the elements of the array `A` is passed to the function through a pointer to them. Such passing objects through pointers to them in C is called passing by reference. Using the pointers you have a direct access to the objects pointed to by the pointers.

Pay attention that that it is better to declare and define the function `revstr` the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * revstr( char *s, size_t n )
{
    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < --n; i++ )
        {
            char c = s[i];
            s[i] = s[n];
            s[n] = c;
        }
    }
    
    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[20];
    
    scanf( "%19s", s );
    
    size_t n = strlen( s );
    
    puts( revstr( s, n ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Stackoverflow
wolfrevokcatS
```

That is the second parameter of the function `revstr` shall have the type `size_t` instead of the type `int` because `size_t` is the return type of the function `strlen`.

The function should return the pointer to the first character of the reversed array.